# Getting `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` in a Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```py
from sys import exit
didlogcorrect = 1
Minecraft = 'Minecraft'
Roblox = 'Roblox'
Exit = 'Exit'
chrome = 'chrome'
  print('Welcome To PotatOS')
  user_input = input("What would you like to do on PotatOS: ")
  if user_input == Roblox:
   print('Unable to connect to wifi Now terminating process')
  elif user_input == Exit:
    exit()
  elif user_input == chrome:
    print('You open Chrome Thinking What should i do now Maybe youtube idk, Then you close Chrome cause your bored!')
  elif user_input == Minecraft:
    print('Crashed, Reason 1, you close it cause your mad it crashed')
else:
  print('PotatOS : BEEERGZ Unable to understand')
```

Crash:

```
Welcome To PotatOS
What would you like to do on PotatOS: Minecraft
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Username/Coding/PotatOS-1.0.1.txt", line 27, in <module>
    if user_input == Roblox:
NameError: name 'Roblox' is not defined
```

I still can't find out why this won't work.

I tried multiple things but it still crashed.

Comment: Function `input` returns 1 value, not 4.

Comment: What do you expect `chrome, Roblox, Exit, Minecraft = input("What would you like to do on PotatOS").split(",",1)` to do?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb There is a chained `.split()` call.

Comment: @MattDMo I Expect it to Ask a question and that's multiple answers for that one question

Comment: You expect it to... what?

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why do you have that `1` in the split method? What do you think it does?

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried using this websites info 
https://plainenglish.io/blog/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python-3

Comment: What is the input that causes the error? We shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @JohnColeman All of the inputs cause the error

Comment: @BryanThePotato I doubt that typing `a,b,c,d` in response to that prompt will cause that error. Please provide a [mcve] that will allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ```What would you like to do on PotatOSa,b,c,d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Username/Coding/PotatOS-1.0.1.txt", line 30, in <module>
    chrome, Roblox, Exit, Minecraft = input("What would you like to do on PotatOS").split(",",1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)```

Comment: Please show an example run of your program. In particular, we need to know what you typed in order to explain why you get this error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The entire code? like do you want a video or something?

Comment: **I have recently have just changed The page can you guys help me with this now**

Comment: @BryanThePotato you need to make sure, that your indentation is uniform. `if`, `elif` and `else` need to be on the same indentation level. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for further help

Comment: @BryanThePotato The easiest way to show an example run of your program is to run it in a terminal, then copy/paste the text into your question.

Comment: @BryanThePotato And if you are encountering a new problem after changing your code, you should post a new question rather than editing this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionalities:
The built-in `input` function writes a prompt to standard output without a trailing newline and then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

As you want to compare values, you need to check the user input like this using `if`/`elif`/`else` statement. Make sure they are on the same indentation level, as python doesn't use braces to distinguish code blocks. See [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) for more information about indentation guidelines.

```py
from sys import exit
didlogcorrect = 1
Minecraft = 'Minecraft'
Roblox = 'Roblox'
Exit = 'Exit'
chrome = 'chrome'

print('Welcome To PotatOS')
user_input = input("What would you like to do on PotatOS: ")
if user_input == Roblox:
    print('Unable to connect to wifi Now terminating process')
elif user_input == Exit:
    exit()
elif user_input == chrome:
    print('You open Chrome Thinking What should i do now Maybe youtube idk, Then you close Chrome cause your bored!')
elif user_input == Minecraft:
    print('Crashed, Reason 1, you close it cause your mad it crashed')
else:
    print('PotatOS : BEEERGZ Unable to understand')
```

Comment: That is doubtless a bug, and OP should benefit from your answer, but I don't think it explains the error message that they got. It reads `(expected 4, got 1)` not `(expected 4, got 2)`. OP hasn't given us any information about the input, but it seems that it isn't splitting at all.

Comment: i like your solution but i don't think this will work or I am just unable to understand

Comment: @BryanThePotato even though the bug involves the function `input()` you still haven't given any concrete example of an input that triggers the bug. Please edit the question to include that crucial piece of information. Help us help you. We shouldn't have to guess what the problem is. Without a [mcve] this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: @BryanThePotato what did you enter to cause this error in the first place?

Comment: I entered one of the variables Like
Minecraft,
Chrome,
Exit,
Roblox.

Comment: @BryanThePotato If you entered just one value, why are you trying to split and assign to 4 variables? The fix might be as simple as dropping `.split()` completely.

Comment: i dont even know what split does I just saw it on a website https://plainenglish.io/blog/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python-3

Comment: Like I showed you, `split` will split a string at a given delimiter. In your case a comma and returns a list

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me this I will put your credit on my project!

Comment: @BryanThePotato Using `split` despite not knowing what it does is dangerously close to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). If you see something in some code that you don't understand -- google it before using it.

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because you're trying to map 4 values (chrome, Roblox, Exit, and Minecraft) while giving only one value from input().

If you want to put 4 different values in one input with space and be mapped into each variables,
e.g.

```
>>> What would you like to do on PotatOS
>>> Here,Type,Your,Answer

--
result:
chrome -> 'Here'
Roblox -> 'Types'
Exit -> 'Your'
Minecraft -> 'Answer'
```

You can try adding `.split()` followed by `input()`

So your code might look like this.
Try to remove the split count value first, and make sure you're doing right in typing in input values.

```py
chrome, Roblox, Exit, Minecraft = input("What would you like to do on PotatOS").split(",")
```

Comment: i like your solution but i don't think this will work or I am just unable to understand

Comment: @BryanThePotato To understand this answer, you will need to learn about sequences such as lists and tuples. You will also need to learn about assigning the elements of a sequence to multiple variables.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest doing

```
user_input = input("What would you like to do on PotatOS")
```

Then doing something with `user_input`. The key here is to keep each line of code as simple as possible. As you learn more about python, you will discover when it is appropriate to chain two method calls together, but until then, don't.

Comment: THis one may ACTULLY work if i knew what to do with User_input is it a variable?

Comment: @BryanThePotato Yes, `user_input` is a variable. It will be a string with whatever the user typed in. I suggest you look for a good python tutorial to help you learn the fundamental concepts of python.